# best way to solve this use case in django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a usecase that there is a user table and a skill table .

1 user can have multiple skills , for example   `writing , scalping , coding` etc upto 50

so what is best way to save this ?  from my search I came to conclusion that ManyToMany field is best here like this

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class User(models.Model):
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True, null=True)
```

but while getting data I have to reverse queries aswell like getting all users having a specific skill for example `writing` . I am go on right way or not . please any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I would also use a ManyToMany relationship, but I would define a through model as this can give more flexibility to the relationship.
You can read about it over here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

My code would probably look like this:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class User(models.Model):
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, through="UserSkillRelation")

class UserSkillRelation(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This will also allow you to add fields to the relationship afterwards.

Comment: and can you please tell how I can query which I mentioned above ?

Comment: Some examples: user.skills_set.filter(name="swimming") or user.skills_set.filter(userskillrelation__updated__lt=datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)). 1 way I like to check what the name of the relationship is is by user dir(user) or dir(skill) on an object and you will find out how you can reverse the relationship. Also please check the link I posted, as it contains all you need, but with band members instead of skillsets.

Comment: got it thanks, having difficulties to add data in this. can you please tell how I can do this